# Bootstrap modal from modal not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am launching a modal off a modal and it isn't appearing over the first modal.  My modals have events called when they are launched:

```
$("#noteModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});

$("#notesModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
```

The modal fires fine but doesn't appear over the first modal.  If i click anywhere on screen the second modal acts as if it disappears then the first modal is still shown.

I've tried doing hide / show on the first and second modal but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [Multiple open modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). From the docs: *Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.*

Comment: use $('#noteModal').modal('hide'); for the second modal, and use $('#notesModal').modal('hide'); for the first modal.

Comment: @FrayneKonok ive tried using those on click but it would hide the notemodal but never show the notes modal

Comment: you can try this http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html

Comment: so how  can you say "it isn't appearing over the first modal"??

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `hidden.bs.modal` event on the first modal to show your second modal, while the button inside the first modal will hide the first modal on click.

Sounds stupid, i know, but here is an example.
This will not stack the modal windows on top of each other though.
If you want them to stack i would say you go with what ***Steve*** suggested in the comment.

And just for the record:

> [**Modals** modal.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> **Multiple open modals not supported**
>
> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

```js
var $firstModal = $('#first-modal'),
    $secondModal = $('#second-modal'),
    $innerModalBtn = $firstModal.find('.btn-block');


$firstModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $secondModal.modal('show');
})

$innerModalBtn.on('click', function() {
  $firstModal.modal('hide');
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <button type="button" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#first-modal">Open Modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="first-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">First Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Open Second Modal</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


<div id="second-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Second Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```